# JavaScript Syntax Error - Unknown Cause

Tags: javascript, php, csv

can you please recommend a better way at creating a .CSV file using JavaScript than my method below, it was the best I could find after searching the previous threads on here. Everything was pretty much okay till I started adding loads and loads of of rows to the data array, as you will see below.

```
var data = 
[
  ["Thermal Store Summary:"] + "\n",
  ["Cylinder:", "", cylinder, "", cylinder2] + "\n",
  ["Heat Exchanger:", "", heatex, "", heatex2] + "\n",
  ["Immersion Heaters:", "", heater, "", heater2] + "\n", 

  **// About 30 or so entries with no problem, didn't work with any more **
];
```

Here are the variables where the id and value of a select menu option is stored.

```
var cylinder = document.getElementById("heatex").options[document.getElementById("heatex").selectedIndex].id;
var heatex = document.getElementById("heatex").options[document.getElementById("heatex").selectedIndex].id;
var heater = document.getElementById("heater").options[document.getElementById("heater").selectedIndex].id;
var cylinder2 = document.getElementById("cylinder").options[document.getElementById("cylinder").selectedIndex].value;
var heatex2 = document.getElementById("heatex").options[document.getElementById("heatex").selectedIndex].value
var heater2 = document.getElementById("heater").options[document.getElementById("heater").selectedIndex].value
```

And here's the code that currently creates the .CSV file:

```
var csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
data.forEach
(
  function(infoArray, index)
  {
    dataString = infoArray;
    csvContent += index < infoArray.length ? dataString+ "" : dataString;
  }
); 

encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
```

As for the download itself, I used to have it auto-download at the end but it stopped after I tried adding more than 30 entries. I moved the code to a seperate function (called by a button) which forced the download which would fail as there was "no file".

```
function download_csv()
  {
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
    link.setAttribute("download", "quote.csv");
    link.click();
  }
```

Any and all help appreciated, ideally a fix to my current solution but also willing to try a new method all together.

Comment: What are you expecting `data` to be? You're declaring it as an array - then adding sub arrays, but then appending `\n` to the sub arrays ( (which in turn would convert them back to strings - don't mix strings with arrays!).

Comment: I only added the \n after it failed to start adding the data to a new row itself. It worked for 4/5 rows but after that it started piling everything into the 6th row and I had to put the \n's in which worked till I got to over 30 entries, ah its confusing...

Comment: kindly change the heading of your error from "PHP Syntax Error - Unknown Cause" to "javascript Syntax Error - Unknown Cause".

Comment: You've mentioned a PHP syntax error in the title, but as far as I can tell there's not a single line of PHP or any mention of an error message in your question.

Answer (score 1):

URLs have a maximum length which varies from browser to browser, and this applies to the size of request you can handle with the `data:` style requests.

One cumbersome but easy to apply fix would be to pass the content to the server as POST data, and have it returned with a really simple `echo $_POST['csvData'];` - But only do something so trivial for a prototype, it's not a really viable solution!